# TailwindCSS custom dropdown expanding parent

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm building a custom dropdown with TailwindCSS

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
                <div class="px-4 mt-3 lg:mt-0">
                    <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl rounded-lg mx-auto">
                        <div class="py-4 w-full border-r border-gray-300">
                            <h2 class="text-gray-900 text-xl mb-3 px-4">All Courses</h2>
                            <div class="relative mt-1 px-4 grid grid-cols-12">
                                <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-10">
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded-none border-gray-300 rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline lg:rounded-r-none" type="search" placeholder="Search a course...">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2">
                                    <!-- To be separated on his own component later -->
                                    <button @click="openfilterDropdown = !openfilterDropdown" class="lg:rounded-l-none mt-2 lg:mt-0 bg-gray-200 transition ease-in-out duration-300 hover:bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center w-full">
                                        <span class="mx-auto">
                                            <i class="fas fa-filter mr-2"></i>
                                            Select Filter
                                        </span>
                                    </button>

                                    <transition name="fadeUp" appear>
                                        <div v-if="openfilterDropdown" class="right-0 mt-2 w-48 bg-white rounded-md overflow-hidden shadow-xl z-50 w-full">
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-800 border-b hover:bg-gray-200"><span class="text-gray-600">Category 1</span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </transition>
                                    <!-- -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

The thing is, when it's "opened" the parent container expands.

[image]

[image]

How can i make so that when the dropdown is open, it doesn't expand its parent container, so that it looks just like when its closed, but with the dropdown items shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div class="relative mt-1 px-4 grid grid-cols-12">` is containing the dropdown to be within the "white" container.

You need to make the dropdown relative to the parent of it to show up above it.

Here is the demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/kW9w90OJW5

Comment: yw! I learned of this recently as well and learned while remembering :)